# How to use useShinydashboard()?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to be able to choose which `valueBox` will be modified by the `useShinydashboard()` command and not all as in the example below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$h2("Classic shiny"),
    
    setBackgroundColor(color = "ghostwhite"),
    useShinydashboard(),

    fluidRow(
        
        valueBox(
            tagList("60", tags$sup(style="font-size: 20px", "%")),
            "Approval Rating", icon = icon("line-chart"), color = "green"
        ),
        valueBox(
            htmlOutput("progress"), "Progress", icon = icon("users"), color = "purple"
        )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$orderNum <- renderText({
        prettyNum(input$orders, big.mark=",")
    })
    
    output$progress <- renderUI({
        tagList(input$progress, tags$sup(style="font-size: 20px", "%"))
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**### EDIT**

How is adding `useShinydashboard()`

[image]

Without `useShinydashboard()` it looks like this

[image]

I want the first option, so I must add `useShinydashboard()`.
The first `valueBox` is generated by

```
valueBox(value=div(paste(1.51,"(1 óbito a cada 66 casos)"),style="font-size:25px;"),
               subtitle = tags$div(HTML('<b style = "padding-left:10px;font-size:16px">LETALIDADE</b>')),
               width=12,
               #icon = icon("skull", lib = "font-awesome"),
               color = "black")
```

The problem is that the `useShinydashboard()` command changes globally. The image below is how it goes without `useShinydashboard()` (this is how I want it)

[image]

But the `useShinydashboard()` command looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use this function above your `ui`.

```
myvalueBox <- function (value, subtitle, icon = NULL, color = "white", width = 4, href = NULL) 
{
  #shinydashboard:::validateColor(color)
  if (!is.null(icon)) 
    shinydashboard:::tagAssert(icon, type = "i")
  boxContent <- div(class = paste0("small-box bg-", color), 
                    div(class = "inner", h3(value), p(subtitle)), if (!is.null(icon)) 
                      div(class = "icon-large", icon))
  if (!is.null(href)) 
    boxContent <- a(href = href, boxContent)
  div(class = if (!is.null(width)) 
    paste0("col-sm-", width), boxContent)
}
```

Then replace `valueBox()` with `myvalueBox` in your program.

Comment: I would like the appearance to look like I am not using `useShinydashboard()`, that is, I would like to apply `useShinydashboard()` only locally. As if I could do `useShinydashboard(only what is here will be modified)`.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by:

> to be able to choose which valueBox will be modified

Documentation of `?useShinydashboard()` says, that it allows you to use `shinydashboard` functions, which are not present in `shiny` itself.

`valueBox()` is a `shinydashboard` function, and is not present in `shiny` package at all.

If you want to modify it, and have the 'original' and 'modified' versions available - I suggest duplicating it for that matter, and modifying the duplicate to your needs. You can see the code that the function consists of if you call it in console without parentheses.

```
> shinydashboard::valueBox
function (value, subtitle, icon = NULL, color = "aqua", width = 4, 
    href = NULL) 
{
    validateColor(color)
    if (!is.null(icon)) 
        tagAssert(icon, type = "i")
    boxContent <- div(class = paste0("small-box bg-", color), 
        div(class = "inner", h3(value), p(subtitle)), if (!is.null(icon)) 
            div(class = "icon-large", icon))
    if (!is.null(href)) 
        boxContent <- a(href = href, boxContent)
    div(class = if (!is.null(width)) 
        paste0("col-sm-", width), boxContent)
}
<bytecode: 0x7fb528f7f648>
<environment: namespace:shinydashboard>
```

Modify it to your needs and save as a different function.

P.S. if you just copy this code to a new function, it will give you errors as this particular function runs another package-related function inside of it. So, you have to change `validateColor()` to `shinydashboard:::validateColor()`.

Comment: I added more information. I was unable to use your solution without `useShinydashboard()`