# How do you adjust the width of custom valueboxes in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, reactive-programming, shinydashboard

I have 2 value boxes with custom colors that I want to customize how much space (width) they take up across the row. However, R ignores my width argument in the valueBox() command from shinydashboard, which I assume is due to me wrapping it in tags to change the colors.

I tried to workaround this limitation by wrapping the output in fluidRow() and then specifying column width, but that yields the weird output below (see screenshot).

Without removing my code regarding the colors, how can I specify the width of each individual value box?

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

navy_inner_box <- "#total_fails .inner{ background-color: navy};"
yellow_inner_box <- "#total_perfect .inner , p , h3 { background-color: yellow};"


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput(inputId = "greeting",
                      label = "Say hi!"),
            actionButton(inputId = "submit", 
                         label = "Submit")
            
        ),
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                tags$style(yellow_inner_box),
                tags$style(navy_inner_box),
                column(6, valueBoxOutput("total_perfect")),
                column(9, valueBoxOutput("total_fails"))
            ))
    ))
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"),
                   grade = c(50, 100, 100))
    
    
    output$total_perfect <- renderValueBox({
        shiny::req(input$greeting)
        shiny::req(input$submit)
        if(input$greeting == "hi!") {
            num_100s <- data %>% filter(grade == 100) %>% nrow()
            valueBox(value = tags$p(num_100s, style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: red"),
                     subtitle = tags$p("Number of Perfect Scores", style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: red"))        }
    })
    
    output$total_fails <- renderValueBox({
        shiny::req(input$greeting)
        shiny::req(input$submit)
        if(input$greeting == "hi!") {
            num_50s <- data %>% filter(grade == 50) %>% nrow()
            valueBox(value = tags$p(num_50s, style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: navy"),
                     subtitle = tags$p("Number of Total Failures", style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: navy"))}
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Visualization of R's bizarre way of reading my column specification. In addition, sometimes it cuts off information too.

[image]

Edit:

Adding screenshot when I try first comment and code I used:

[image]

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

navy_inner_box <- "#total_fails .inner{ background-color: navy};"
yellow_inner_box <- "#total_perfect .inner , p , h3 { background-color: yellow};"


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput(inputId = "greeting",
                      label = "Say hi!"),
            actionButton(inputId = "submit", 
                         label = "Submit")
            
        ),
        mainPanel(
                tags$style(yellow_inner_box),
                tags$style(navy_inner_box),
                fluidRow(column(6), column(3, valueBoxOutput("total_perfect")), column(3)),
                fluidRow(column(9, valueBoxOutput("total_fails")), column(3))
            ))
    )
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"),
                   grade = c(50, 100, 100))
    
    
    output$total_perfect <- renderValueBox({
        shiny::req(input$greeting)
        shiny::req(input$submit)
        if(input$greeting == "hi!") {
            num_100s <- data %>% filter(grade == 100) %>% nrow()
            valueBox(value = tags$p(num_100s, style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: red"),
                     subtitle = tags$p("Number of Perfect Scores", style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: red"))        }
    })
    
    output$total_fails <- renderValueBox({
        shiny::req(input$greeting)
        shiny::req(input$submit)
        if(input$greeting == "hi!") {
            num_50s <- data %>% filter(grade == 50) %>% nrow()
            valueBox(value = tags$p(num_50s, style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: navy"),
                     subtitle = tags$p("Number of Total Failures", style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: navy"))}
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? This looks to be working as intended. I'm thinking maybe you want to center the value boxes themselves? You can do so by wrapping them in blank columns like `fluidRow(column(3),column(6,valueBoxOutput()),column(3))`? The total of the columns in each row should add up to 12 if that helps.

Comment: @Baroque, it's inconsistent in it's display for some reason. Also, I tried your suggestion because the crookedness of the boxes was difficult as well. However, when I try the code you suggested, it looks like the above. When I do just one call to fluid row, it cuts of large parts of the box as well.

Comment: I checked out `?valueBox` because I never use the things (yet), and it says "Value boxes are meant to be placed in the main body of a dashboard." This issue could be caused because you're placing them in a standard shiny app instead of a `dashboardPage(dashboardBody(... valueBoxOutput()...))` format. Check out this page to learn more about `shinydashboard` UI format: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html

Comment: @Baroque, thanks for your help. That's correct, but I just discovered that the use of the useShinydashboard() from function from the shinyWidgets package enables the seamless use of value boxes outside of the strict shinydashboard structure. If interested, see my answer I posted below. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234722/how-to-use-useshinydashboard).

The key is to use the `useShinydashboard()` function from the `shinyWidgets` package. By adding this one line of code underneath the `fluidPage()` call, you are able to seamlessly use value and info boxes and can change their width using the column argument. One important callout is that instead of using the `valueBoxOutput()` function, you instead will use the `uiOutput` function within the main panel. Everything within the `renderValueBox()` is the same however.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

navy_inner_box <- "#total_fails .inner , #total_fails p { background-color: navy};"
yellow_inner_box <- "#total_perfect .inner , #total_perfect p { background-color: red};"

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinydashboard(),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput(inputId = "greeting",
                      label = "Say hi!"),
            actionButton(inputId = "submit", 
                         label = "Submit")
            
        ),
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                tags$style(yellow_inner_box),
                tags$style(navy_inner_box),
                column(9, uiOutput("total_perfect")),
                column(3, uiOutput("total_fails"))
            ))
    ))
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"),
                   grade = c(50, 100, 100))
    
    
    output$total_perfect <- renderValueBox({
        shiny::req(input$greeting)
        shiny::req(input$submit)
        if(input$greeting == "hi!") {
            num_100s <- data %>% filter(grade == 100) %>% nrow()
            valueBox(value = tags$p(num_100s, style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: red"),
                     subtitle = tags$p("Number of Perfect Scores", style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: red"))        }
    })
    
    output$total_fails <- renderValueBox({
        shiny::req(input$greeting)
        shiny::req(input$submit)
        if(input$greeting == "hi!") {
            num_50s <- data %>% filter(grade == 50) %>% nrow()
            valueBox(value = tags$p(num_50s, style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: navy"),
                     subtitle = tags$p("Number of Total Failures", style = "text-align:center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: navy"))}
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]